# How to understand $(E_n, ev)$ the lim inf

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading Probability theory but have difficulty understanding this definition:
$(E_n, ev) := \lim \inf E_n := \cup_m\cap_{n\geq m} E_n = \{\omega: \text{for some } m(\omega), \omega \in E_n, \forall n \geq m(\omega)\}$.

(1). First, I set $E_n = \{1,2,3,...,n\}$. Then $\cap_{n\geq m} E_n = E_m$ because $E_n \subset E_{n+1}$. Thus $\cup_m\cap_{n\geq m} E_n = \{1,2,3,4,.......\}$

(2). However, if I set $E_n = \{n, n+1, n+2,...\}$, then $E_n \supset E_{n+1}$. What $\lim\inf E_n$ will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful characterization of $\liminf$ is:

> $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} E_n = \{\omega \in \Omega : \omega \in E_n \text{ for all except finitely many } n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

Using this:

$(1)$ $\liminf_{n\to\infty} E_n = \mathbb{N}$ since:

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} E_n \subseteq \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} E_n = \mathbb{N}$$

$$\text{every }m \in \mathbb{N} \text{ is contained in all $E_n$ for } n \geq m, \text{ thus in infinitely many } E_n \implies \mathbb{N} \subseteq \liminf_{n\to\infty} E_n$$

$(2)$ $\liminf_{n\to\infty} E_n = \emptyset$ since:

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} E_n \subseteq \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} E_n = \mathbb{N}$$

$$\text{every }m \in \mathbb{N} \text{ is contained only in } E_1, \ldots, E_m \text{ so it cannot be in } \liminf_{n\to\infty} E_n \implies \mathbb{N} \cap \liminf_{n\to\infty} E_n = \emptyset$$